# How to skip writing in csv if certain category appears in list?

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to scrape some data and write it in a `CSV` file.

I want to skip writing the row if a certain category appears.

I try this matching it with a particular category with an `if` statement but it's not working and still, the record with the particular category is written to the `CSV` file.

`article_category.text` have the scraped categories that I'm extracting (using BeautifulSoup) from a bunch of `URL`s. When I print `article_category.text` I get following values:

```
Otros Deportes
Fútbol Colombiano
FORO-W
Videos
```

Each `URL` will have only a single category and I want to skip articles where `category` is `FORO-W` or `Videos`:

```py
for article in article_details:
    article_category = article.find('div', {'class' : 'category'})
    article_date = article.find('div', {'class' : 'published-at'})
    article_link = article.find('h3', {'class' : 'title-container'})
    url = article_link.find("a")["href"]
    url = "https://www.eltiempo.com" + url
    if article_category.text=="FORO-W" or article_category.text == "Videos":
        pass
    else:
        csvwriter.writerow([url, article_category.text, article_date.text])
```

[image]

Comment: You say that "it's not working", but *how* is it "not working"? What happens? What's supposed to happen? What is the input? What is the output? Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I told in the same line that I expect it to skip the record but the record with the particular category is still showing up in csv.

Comment: @corralien strip() will only remove the spaces but I want to match it with article_category = article.find('div', {'class' : 'category'}) which Im extracting from webpage. I dont think it would help in matching

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. Where `category` is defined?

Comment: Try *print(category.text)* The output may not be what you were expecting

Comment: @BrutusForcus `print('"' + category.text + '"')` is even better. And might indicate a need for `strip`.

Comment: if I print the category.text it has FORO-W or Videos or other categories.

Comment: Can you give an example value for *article*? Then I'll try it for you

Comment: @Muzi And no leading *or trailing* spaces?

Comment: By the way, what *is* `category`? How is it initialized? From where is it initialized? Please try to create a proper [mre] to show us. And **[edit]** your question to improve it, like showing us the input for the program etc.

Comment: There is nothing in this code that would cause the attributes of *category* to change. Therefore the test should be performed prior to enumeration of *article_details* if only to save time. Having said that, if *category.text* is exactly equal to either of the constant strings, there is no way that *csvwriter.writerow()* will be invoked

Comment: You are assigning a value to `article_category`, and later writing it to file. But you perform the test on `category` which is a different variable. Just change that

Comment: @gimix sorry that was typo

Comment: Does it work now? If not, have you tried printing *article_category.text*? Is there perhaps some leading or trailing whitespace?

Comment: @BrutusForcus Im running the script will post it if it works :)

Comment: @BrutusForcus still same Im attaching the screenshot on posted question

Comment: Foro-W **not** FORO-W

Comment: @Muzi You seem surprised. Did you think that string comparisons in Python were, by default, case insensitive?

Comment: @BrutusForcus yeah I was using the same string for matching in csv and it was finding it so I put the same one in python code.

Comment: Certainly not the cause but this `if article_category.text=="FORO-W" or article_category.text == "Videos":` can be replaced with the more Pythonic and readable equivalent `if article_category.text in ("FORO-W", "Videos"):`. And while we are on it, change the logic to `if article_category.text not in ("FORO-W", "Videos"): # write to the CSV file` and then remove that `pass` nonsense.

Comment: @accdias My mistake. I misread it and have deleted my erroneous comment

Comment: No worries :-D. We all have walked that path sometime.

Comment: But there is room for improvement though: we could use a `set()` instead of a `tuple()` and make the checking faster. Something like `if article_category.text not in {"FORO-W", "Videos"}:` (notice the use of curly braces now).